# I'm Upgrading from mysql to mysqli. I can not get my query to produce a result

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a web site that accesses a database using PHP with MySQL . I am attempting to upgrade the code to use MySqli. I foolishly thought this was going to be simply an update to the code by changing lines such as $result=MySql_query($query) to $result=MySqli_query($query). WRONG! I've since done some research and found the need for more changes than what I assumed (yes I know what they say about AssUMe). I have made some simple changes but I can not get my query to give me a result. Yes I have done some research in this, but I am asking for help here to save me time.

To show you what I have tried I have copied my test code. Establishing the connect seems to be working, but that is the end of my success. In this example I am simply trying to get the number of rows in a table, but not having any luck. I'm asking what is a simple fix to this test code I am showing.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=windows-1252" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<title>Data Access Test</title>
<?php
  $servername = "localhost";
  $username = "*********";
  $password = "##########";
  $dbname = "xxxxxxxxxxx";
  $link = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
   if ($link -> connect_errorno)
  {
    echo "failed to connect to database " . $link -> connect_error;
    exit();
  }
  else
  {
  echo "success";
  };
  echo "trying query";
  $query = "SELECT * FROM administrative where 1";
  echo $query;
  $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
  $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
  echo " Number of rows = ". $numrows;
?>
</head>

<body>

</body>

</html>
```

The result is: success; trying query;SELECT * FROM administrative where 1 Number of rows =

Thank you in advance for anyone that can help.

Comment: You need to enable php error reporting

Comment: Thank You! It was as simple as that. I have a new Web Host and there were many changes that they failed to let us know about. I no longer have access to php.ini and have to set php error reporting differently. I did not realize it wasnt working. My problem was resolved because of your suggestion.